# Add/Remove a MediaStream in WebRTC Peer connection in android

Tags: webrtc, mediastream

I use libjingle:11139@aar library to build a chat app in Android platform.

The problem of adding/removing a mediastream dynamically from a RTCPeerConnection is explained in many stackoverflow threads but all of them seems to be related to JavaScript. I could not find any thread that explains in detail about the usage/sequence of execution in Java/android application.

I have read in many places that after adding a mediastream, a new sdp has to be raised to the peer about the addition of the stream. But when a new sdp offer is created the current peer connection is LOST. I get onIceConnectionChange(CLOSED) in the peer that initiates the sdp offer (after adding a mediastream).
Is this the expected behaviour ?

Another observation is that, after adding a mediastream to the peerconnection a RenogotiationNeeded() notification is received in the peer that just added the stream. On this notification, if a createOffer() is sent then the peerConnection is lost.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: There are some issues when renewing the stream within webrtc on browsers, not sure if it's with chrome or firefox, but the solution is to kill the current connection and create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution when I come back to the WebRTC, here you can disabled local video for only streaming one side of peer:
In class **PeerConnectionClient** (I'm talking in Java-Android project), write a function below and call it when video is calling:

```
 //Hieu: disabled receive peer video for aircraft streaming only
  public void setMyVideoEnabled(final boolean enable) {
    executor.execute(() -> {
      renderVideo = enable;
      if (remoteVideoTrack != null) {
        remoteVideoTrack.setEnabled(renderVideo);
      }
    });
  }
```

I haven't tried with audio but I think we can do it as same as this function.
For example, I call that function on button switch camera in example of WebRTC code: **CallActivity.java**

```
@Override
  public void onCameraSwitch() {
    if (peerConnectionClient != null) {
      //peerConnectionClient.switchCamera();
      peerConnectionClient.setMyVideoEnabled(false);
    }
  }
```

Link of example of Google:
https://webrtc.org/native-code/android/
Path:
src/examples/androidapp
Have funs :)